# formatting date in angularJS table

Tags: angularjs, datetime, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am creating a web app in angularJS I have a date in the following format

> "response.data[0].Date = "/Date(1539887400000)/"

I can convert this date into normal `MM-DD-YYYY` with moment, like this

```
moment(response.data[0].Date).format('DD-MM-YYYY');
```

but while binding the data into table with ng-repeat I am not able to achieve this

I did something like this

```
<td>{{d.Date| date:'DD-MM-YYYY' }}</td>
```

but in table it still showing like `/Date(1539887400000)/`

what I need to do to convert `/Date(1539887400000)/` into DD-MM-YYYY

Comment: You could create a custom filter to return moment(response.data[0].Date).format('DD-MM-YYYY'); for your values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is because the `date` filter you are using is an AngularJS defined one, and is designed to work on date objects, the number of seconds since the epoch, or specifically formatted strings (see: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date). In your case, you are passing in a string `"Date(1539887400000)"`, which doesn't adhere to any of specific formats that the `date` argument of the filter expects. Here are a few ways I would think about solving this:

- You could initialize the date option after you have fetched the data from the database. An example would be: `$scope.testDate = new Date(1539887400000);`. You can then use the regular angular date filter on this object: `{{testDate | date: 'dd-MM-yyyy'}}`.
- You can use angular-moment (link: https://github.com/urish/angular-moment), which has more features than the regular angularJS date filter. You can then use the `amDateFormat` and pass your string in, like so: `{{d.Date | amDateFormat: 'DD-MM-YYYY'}}`
- You could parse out the number from the string that you currently have. Since the regular angularJS `date` filter can accept a number (seconds since epoch) as it's argument, it will properly format it.

See an example plunker here showing some of these in action: https://plnkr.co/edit/quCvL3GhSux8ctYQqAwA